# Does parasitic capacitance contribute to the magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, capacitance, inductance

When modeling a real inductor, typically the equivalent circuit is the following one:
[image: Real inductor model]

[Source](https://community.element14.com/challenges-projects/design-challenges/experimenting-with-magnetic-components/b/blog/posts/ideal-vs-real-inductors-part-1---understanding-the-inductor)

A series resistance and parallel capacitor is added.
This model works very well to explain the following impedance graph:
[image: Impedance graph]

[Same Source](https://community.element14.com/challenges-projects/design-challenges/experimenting-with-magnetic-components/b/blog/posts/ideal-vs-real-inductors-part-1---understanding-the-inductor)

If I now draw what I imagine would be seen on that inductor whilst being driven by an AC source at ports 1 and 2:
[image: Real inductor]

In this image the purple arrows depict the current inside the inductor and the positive and negative charges are the charges held by the parasitic capacitance. These charges as I understand it are located at the surface of the inductor wire and due to the AC source they form a surface current.

It is well known that the magnetic flux of an inductor is $\phi = L I$ and therefore to me this $I$ is the sum of both currents, that is, the current through the capacitor branch plus the current through the inductor + resistor in the equivalent circuit model.

However, I remember reading from somewhere that only the current flowing through the inductor + resistor from the circuit model would be the actual current that generates the magnetic flux. This would make sense to me if only the capacitor wasn't actually parasitic to the inductor, but the way I see it is that the surface current caused by the capacitance should contribute to the magnetic flux.

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume an ideal conductor.

An ideal conductor forces the electric field to zero parallel to its surface. That means that there cannot be a displacement current along the wire: there's only real current. There is an electric field perpendicular to the wire surface associated with the displacement current through the inter-winding capacitance.

Comment: I agree that displacement current is not real current, but I believe that the charges stored are distributed throughout the entire conductor, as can be seen in my drawing, thus forming a surface current.
So unfortunately I don't see how this answer answers my question. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @rr1303 There's no distributed charge interior to an (ideal) capacitor.

Comment: In the classical two plate capacitor, indeed there are no charges stored within the dielectric, only at the surface of the two plates. However what we are dealing here is quite different since the actual plates from the classical case are now the windings of the inductor which extend the full length of our (parasitic) capacitor and so it seems that the charges are stored at the surface of the windings.

Comment: @rr1303 Why should there be charge there? The capacitive displacement current involves no real charge, and it only needs to be balanced by real charge at the ends of the inductor.

Comment: That’s an interesting way of looking at it. So you believe that there are big blobs of charge only at the ends of the inductor and none on the windings?

Comment: @rr1303 Imagine a stack of rings instead of a coil. Float the interior rings, connect the end rings to a capacitance meter. The interior rings cannot charge, since they aren't connected to anything. The stack, however, will have a capacitance similar to the coil: the ring-ring capacitance is about the same as the turn-turn capacitance.

Comment: The rings analogy is very clear, but now imagine that the rings are all connected one to another via an ideal conductor (as in the case of the windings in the inductor), can one now claim that there are no charges in the inner rings?

Comment: @rr1303 If they were charging the way you assume, you couldn't model it as a stack of capacitors.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I'm getting the idea. I'll think about it for a bit.